# Determine a sum in a large data set

Tags: matlab, vector, sum, mathematical-optimization

Say for example that I have the data set

```
data = [2 4 12.3 54.2 0.3 11 5 3];
```

I need to find which of the variables in the data set that sums up to a specific value, for example: 8. In this case this would result in 5 + 3 = 8.

How can I achieve this?

thanks

Comment: What if there are multiple combination of variables that add up to the number e.g. `data = [4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 5, 3]` now you can make `8` by going `5+3` or `4+4` or `6+2` or `4+2+2` or `4+2+2` using the other `4`...

Comment: The dataset is bills so they should not add up to the same sum, e.g. data = [107,38 17034,89 1201,10] etc. There is of course a probability, but It should be low

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's not always a solution to such problems, and it might be difficult to find.

You may find [`intlinprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html) usefull:

```
n = numel(data);
sumTo = 8;  %// the target sum
x = intlinprog(zeros(n,1), 1:n, [], [], data, sumTo, zeros(n,1), ones(n,1));
sel = find(sel);
```

`sel` should contain the indices of elements of `data` which sum equals to `sumTo`.
That is, `sum(data(sel))==sumTo`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following works. I added a three in the list just for generalizing a bit more.

```
data = [2 4 12.3 54.2 0.3 11 5 3 3];
a=nchoosek(data,2); %all perms
b=sum(a,2);
ii=find(b==8); %find perms summing up to 8
c=nchoosek(1:numel(data),2); %indexes of all perms
d=c(ii,:) %are the indexes
e=data(d) %are the values summing up to 8

d =

     7     8
     7     9


e =

     5     3
     5     3
```

Comment: what if `data` has a little more than 9 elements, say 100? what about the solution `2+3+3=8`?

Comment: cannot check it out now. But what about `a=nchoosek(data,3)` and `c=nchoosek(1:numel(data),3)`?

Comment: please see a more general solution using `perms` in my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to go for an exhaustive search type of solution (along the lines proposed by [A_C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671716/1714410)), you can use [`perms`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html):

```
n = numel(data);
sumTo = 8;  %// target sum
pidx = perms(1:n);  %// indices of all permutations. note the EXPONENTIAL blow
pdata = data(pidx);  %// all permutations
csm = cumsum(pdata, 2);  %// sum along second dim
[r c] = find(csm == sumTo);  %// which perm sum to target sum
if ~isempty(r)
   %// select the first solution
   sel = pidx(r(1), 1:c(1));  %// sum(data(sel))==8
end
```

Comment: hmmm, I wonder if the performance of this solution will increase further by filtering down the dataset, since there are no negative numbers (not sure, but just by observation) any number greater than 8 can just be discarded.

Comment: @GameOfThrows I do not think "brute force" is the right approach here. Personally, I think using `intlinprog` is the proper approach. See my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37671492/1714410).